# Connected App definition in Managed Package

Tags: community, managed-package, appexchange, connected-apps, canvas-app

I added my connected app in my managed package, but when install it in other organization, I find only the "Policy" of my Connected app and not the definition like the configuration of my canvass app which had an access method in **Post** and the Permitted user "**Admin approved users are pre-authorized**".
After installation , i find only the policy of my canvass app with Permitted User "All users may self-authorize" and not find the app with definition for access method in POST.
I would have expected to find the new app with the **new consumer key and consumer secret**
does anyone have an idea? Thank you all